# conception issue with a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many

There is something wrong with my associations.
I want that many VideoPost can refer to the same VideoInformation.
I then thought that the foreign key should be in VideoPost so I started with the 2 models you can see below.
But I can't access to @video_post.video_information (which seems to make sense since there is no association in VideoPost)
How should I do ? I'm a little confuse here

Thanks for any help !

My VideoPost model :

```
# Table name: video_posts
#
#  id                   :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id              :integer
#  video_information_id :integer
#  created_at           :datetime         not null
#  updated_at           :datetime         not null
class VideoPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :video_information_id
end
```

My VideoInformation model :

```
# Table name: video_informations
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  title           :string(255)
#  description     :text
#  keywords        :text
#  duration        :integer
#  video_url       :string(255)
#  thumbnail_small :string(255)
#  thumbnail_large :string(255)
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
class VideoInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :video_posts
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add

```
belongs_to :video_information
```

into video_post.rb since when you're defining association you should do it in both models.

[here is some info](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) you probably want to look at

Comment: Yeah i thought of that but the meaning "VideoPost belongs to VideoInformation" doesn't sounds right to me" (regarding the context). You know what i mean ?

Comment: @Pontek yeah, if you interpret it without taking in attention your use case. It's hard to assume anything without knowing about your use case, but you probably can rename `VideoInformation` into `Video` and I can oversee that you'll inherit `VideoPost` from `Post` to share behavior.